# Issues with form inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, symfony-forms

I have a `PersonType` form and then I have `LegalPersonType` and `NaturalPersonType` forms and both extends from `PersonType` since they have a common field on that form (mapped at Entity level). For example, this is the code for `NaturalPersonType.php`

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Tanane\FrontendBundle\DBAL\Types\CIType;
use Tanane\FrontendBundle\Form\Type\PersonType;

class NaturalPersonType extends PersonType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        $builder
                ->add('identification_type', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => 'Número de Cédula',
                    'choices' => CIType::getChoices()
                ))
                ->add('ci', 'number', array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'maxlength' => 8,
                    ))
                )
                ->add('lives_in_ccs', 'checkbox', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'required' => false,
                    'value' => 1,
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'natural_person';
    }

}
```

Then at SaveFormController/orderAction() I'm doing this:

```
$order = new Orders();
$orderForm = $this->createForm(new OrdersType(array($type)), $order, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('save_order')));
```

But any time I try to render the form I get this error:

> Neither the property "nat" nor one of the methods "getNat()", "nat()",
>   "isNat()", "hasNat()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders".

Relationship are at Entity level, how I fix that error?

Thanks in advance

**1st possible solution**

Following suggestions from user here I change, in `OrderType.php` Form my code to this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Tanane\FrontendBundle\DBAL\Types\SFType;

class OrdersType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $register_type;

    public function __construct($register_type)
    {
        $this->register_type = $register_type;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // here goes $builder with default options remove for see less code

        if ($this->register_type[0] == "natural")
        {
            $builder->add('nat', new NaturalPersonType(), array(
                'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson'
            ));
        }
        elseif ($this->register_type[0] == "legal")
        {
            $builder->add('leg', new LegalPersonType(), array(
                'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\LegalPerson'
            ));
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Tanane\FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders',
            'render_fieldset' => FALSE,
            'show_legend' => FALSE
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'orders';
    }

}
```

I've fixed by adding `'mapped' => FALSE` on each new FormType I add in `OrdersType` but I don't know if this is the right. Also, if I'm defining the `data_class` here, and `NaturalType` will never be access directly just trough `OrdersType` should I remove the default options from that form or should I leave them there? How can I fix the problem now? What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question but maybe could solve some problem before that happens...

I don't remember to have seen it's possible to extend a form like this instead of extend `AbstractType`, but as explained in the docs, if you have common fields to share between different types of forms you should use the native framework modularity offered by [inherit_data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html).

If you need something more specific (some special methods to execute on some field) you can [create a new field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) or [extend an existing one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html) using `AbstractTypeExtension`.

**EDIT**:

I don't know exactly why you are using this approach (that I never used in my projects) but IMO `PersonType`, `NaturalPersonType` and `LegalPersonType` should be only "FormType/FieldType" initialized with `inherit_data` (and not entities like in your code) that contains the fields related to their use, while `OrdersType` should be composed with the block of forms needed to the type of person who fills it and with `data_class` setted on the UNIQUE entity that store the data outputted by the form.

Comment: Hi, can you take a look at my edition? I'm still having some issues after try to get code working with your suggestion